# Run FME workspace using python

Tags: python, fme-form

[image: error]I'm trying to run a second workspace using python command in "Shutdown Python Script" in the first workspace using the following command. But its giving me an error. Is there anything I need to do different? I am using FME 2012 SP 2

Thanks, 
Sam

So as suggested by Safe tech support, I created a batch file with the following code:

`fme.exe c:\test2.fmw --SourceDataset_ARCGIS_LAYER C:\ScratchParcel\DevEnv.gdb\AddressPoint --DestDataset_SHAPE C:\temp`

and added the following code in the shutdown python script window:

`import os
os.system("C:\\temp\\test.bat")`

When I run it, although it says transaction was successful, I don't get any results i.e., the output shapefile is not created.

Comment: Is there a test2.log in the same folder as test2.fmw? If that's being created when you run the batch file then it's running properly and the workspace itself isn't working correctly.

Comment: There is no log file being created. So does this mean there is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Does it work if you run the batch file directly? Run it from a command window or add a `pause` statement so it doesn't disappear before you can see what it says.

Comment: I added pause statement to the batch file and there was a tanslation failed message. I uploaded the screen shot of it but it disappeared. Is there any other way to upload the image?

Comment: Assuming you can run the test2.fmw workspace in workbench, try deleting the --Source/DestDataset params and simply running 'fme.exe c:\test2.fmw'.

Comment: I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Can you run test2.fmw in Workbench?  Is the fme.exe in your path part of the same installed build as Workbench?

Comment: That's it. fme.exe in my path is different from what I'm running my workbench. I have both FME 2011 and 2012 installed in my machine. Now how do I tell it to run a specific one?

Comment: Use the full path to fme.exe using something like 'c:\fme2012\fme.exe c:\test2.fmw'.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an expansion of the previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Python doesn't look syntactically valid.  Try

```
import os
os.system("fme.exe C:\\temp\\test2.fmw --SourceDataset_ARCGIS_LAYER C:\\ScratchParcel\\DevEnv.gdb\\AddressPoint --DestDataset_SHAPE C:\\temp")
```

I've added the parens and quotes around the string you are passing to os.system, and escaped the backslashes.

**Update:**
In addition, the fme.exe in your path is different than the fme.exe being run by Workbench.  Explicitly specify the path to the fme.exe you want to run:

```
os.system("c:\\pathToFme\\fme.exe test2.fmw")
```

or, perhaps in this more future proof manner

```
os.system(os.path.join(os.environ['FME_HOME'], "fme.exe") + " test2.fmw")
```

which says "run using the fme.exe that we are currently running".

Comment: Raven, I am still getting error with the python execution.

Comment: What error do you get?  Is it a Python error or an FME error?

Comment: The logfile says its successful but I dont see any results. "FME_END_PYTHON: evaluating python script from string...
FME_END_PYTHON: python script execution complete."

Comment: There should be a log file left over from the fme.exe execution invoked by your end Python.  You can override the log location in the test2.fmw sub-workspace if you are having trouble finding it.  (Can be done via command line too, but I can't remember how offhand.)

Answer (score 1):

FME start up and shutdown scripts (FME, Python and Oracle)

only screenshots of the startup/shutdown process so you will have to create your own.

[image]

The whole process is a multi-stage system, requiring the use of FME startup and shutdown scripts.

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Example-Workflow-using-FME-Python-and-Oracle

Comment: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Python-and-FME-Basics#heading_toc_j_2 has editable scripts in the sample-workspaces.zip